# boolean logic case to construct truth table

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

So I have this boolean logic case.

three variables x, y, and z. The (ternary) parity function p(x, y, z) is a boolean function with value

*• F, if an even number of the inputs x, y, and z have truth value T*

*• T, if an odd number of inputs have truth value T*

this is my truth table (ill put just a few case) below

x y z - p(x, y, z)

F F F     (?)

F F T evaluates to T because there is one T which is odd

F T T evaluates to F because there is two T which is even

my question is that, what if all of the three input evaluates to F. It is neither T odd or T false. So what would it evaluates to?

Comment: [0 is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero) So technically you have an even number of parameters with a value of T when you have none

Comment: Then F F F should evaluates to T? but technically F F F means there are three Fs which corresponds to odd number of Fs? How can that evaluate to T?

Comment: It will evaluate to F as the number of T is 0 i.e. even

Comment: We are counting the occurence of T in the input @MdJohirulIslam if there is even number of T's it will evaluate to F. if there is odd number of T's it will evaluate to T.

Comment: @BorisA It will evaluate to F because you count the number of T. It is 0. You check if 0 is even. It is, so you return F. Your deffinition only says _if the number is even_ not that there should be at least one

Comment: can you post the answer. so i can checklist it

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an even number x is that it is divisible by 2 with no remainder. 0/2 = 0, so if there are zero T, it will evaluate to F